# i want to trace this method to know why it stop looping after the second record

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, odoo

i wanna to make a button to loop in all records and do a method that makes a list from ranges between tow fields and pop another record from the list and but the value in result field

i make it like in the code below and it work well just in the first record and the second record it working but without remove the record form the list and it's important for me to remove it like
then it stop working

```
class relate(models.Model):
_name = 'relate'
_rec_name = 'car'

@api.multi
@api.onchange('start', 'end', 'ignore')
def years_rang(self):
    for rec in self.search([]):
        if not rec.rang:
            record = [int(x) for x in range(int(rec.start), int(rec.end) + 1)]
            list = []
            if rec.ignore:
                try:
                    record.remove(int(self.ignore))
                    list= []
                    print(record)
                except ValueError:
                    return {'warning': {'title': 'Warning!', 'message': "the Ignored year doesn't in range"}}
                else:
                    for item in record:
                        range_id = self.env['yearrange'].create({'name': str(item)})
                        list.append(range_id.id)
                    rec.rang = [(4, x, None) for x in list]
        else:
            return

start = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
end = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
rang = fields.One2many(comodel_name="yearrange", inverse_name="product_id", store=True, string="Years" ,)
ignore = fields.Char(string="Ignore", required=False, )

class yearrange(models.Model):
_name = 'yearrange'
_rec_name = 'name'

name = fields.Char()
product_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="relate")
```

any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: You've got a `return` statement in your exception handling, and also in the main `else` clause. Either of those `return` statements will exit the function (and consequently, the `for rec` loop. Since we can't see the input, it's impossible to really give more detail about *why* your code is exiting earlier than you think it should, but that would be a good place to start debugging.

Answer (score 3):

- Adding `print()` in key parts helps tracing a lot.
- If more is needed, `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` would get you into a debugger REPL, provided that the process has a terminal (not running in a Lambda, etc).
- The lack of explanation of what this code is doing and what kind of data it works on prevents an uninvolved observer from detecting any data-related bugs in it. What does `self.search([])` even return?
- Shadowing built-in identifiers like `list` is a bad idea, about as bad as having non-descriptive names like `list`.